# Retrieve array data from yaml file Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, yaml

I have the following array in a yaml file:

```
error_messages:
  - 'Error! There is no registration number'
  - 'Error! Event is not added'
```

I am reading data from this file as following:

```
$common_test_data['error_messages[0]']
```

I've initialized my yaml file in global var:

```
$common_test_data =  YAML.load_file("#{Dir.pwd}/test_data/common_data.yml")
```

But data unfortunately is not retrieved from yaml array. Maybe there is specific way to retrieve data from yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve it in the following way:
`$common_test_data['error_messages'][0]`

`$common_test_data` is a Hash.
`$common_test_data['error_messages']` is an Array.

Comment: Then you can select my unswer as the solution :-)

Comment: My reputation is too low yet, sorry )

Comment: @ВасисуалияЛоханкина that's temporary problem ☺